# Second sequential ajax call response not coming into its success function

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have made two sequential ajax call successfully but the response of second Ajax call from controller is not coming into the respective Ajax success function.

**Ajax Function**

```
        $(document).on("click", "#AddTempStock", function () {
            var formData = $("#StockItemEntryForm").serialize();               
            var prodId =   $("#addMoreStock").data("prod-id");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../StockTracker/PersistTempStockItem?prodId=' + prodId,
                data: formData,
                success: function (data) {

                    var msg = '' + data + '';

                    if (data != null) {
                        if (data == 'SUCCESS')
                        {   // Hiding Popup
                            $('#GenericPopup').modal('hide');
                            msg = 'Stock against ' + prodId + ' saved successfully.';   
                        }                           
                        // showing message
                        Messenger().post({
                            message: msg,
                            type: 'error',
                            showCloseButton: true
                        });
                    }
                },
                complete: function (data1)
                {
                    //Showing temporarily Added stock in StockTracker Homepage
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: '../StockTracker/GetTempStockView',
                        data: { "UserName": '@user', "SeasonYear": '@Season', "Company": '@CompName' },
```

Below piece of code is not executing.
ActionMethod is called in controller and returning.

```
                        success: function (data1) {
                            if (data1 != null) {
                                $('.temp-added-stock').html(data1);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can you check networks in your developer tool where this async call is present. Check the status and response of the call.

Comment: If you put `alert('bob');` inside of `complete: function (data1)` does an alert popup?

Comment: @mjwills alert is not working.

Comment: but is your call successfull? Maybe you can debug on server to see what result come back?

Comment: Thanks @NikhilKoul for suggesting to check the status and response in developer tool. I found out that the controller is returning partial view in response with appropriate model. But there was an error in accessing attributes of that model on the partial view itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thanks everyone for suggesting the different ways**

When I inspected the network tab in developer tools, I found out that there was an error(with status code 500) mentioned there with respect to my response url.

**Controller Code**

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetTempStockView(string UserName, string SeasonYear, string Company) 
    {

        TempStockItem temp = new TempStockItem();
        DataTable dt = temp.GetTempStockItems(UserName, Company, SeasonYear);
        temp.SetTempStockItems(dt);
        return PartialView("_TempStockView",temp);

    }
```

Actually there was an error in accessing the attributes of the model in the _TempStockView. After correction the code run as expected. Below is the code which was corrected

```
<img class="thumbnail img-rounded" id="@s.StockProduct.prodid" src="@Models.util.GetImgListFromDB(s.StockProduct.prodid)[0].img" width="70" height="70" style=" margin-bottom: 0px;" />
```